# Using JQuery editInPlace on Ajax injected HTML

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, inject

I am successfully using JQuery editInPlace plug-in on a static HTML page.

It's not working with the same HTML when the HTML is injected by an Ajax call.

I understand that using .on() such as '$('.edit_inplace_field').on(...)' should help in resolving the problem but I'm not sure how exactly it should be done for this specific plug-in.

The plug-in: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-in-place-editor/

The working static HTML code looks like:

```
<p id="name_id" style="background-color: transparent; 
      "class="edit_inplace_field">Enter Name</p>
```

The associated script that is used with the static HTML:

```
$('.edit_inplace_field').editInPlace({
    callback: function(unused, enteredText) { return enteredText; },
// url: './server.php',
show_buttons: false
});
```

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Using the information pointed by:
1. Dave Hauenstein - the jquery live api and by
2. Using an example on http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_live_newel I resolve the above.

The event in use above was the **click** event. With this in mind the solution:
Putting the above jquery code inside a .live() function:

```
$('.edit_inplace_field').live("click",function() {  
             // --> code from above here, object is replaced by $(this)
     $(this).editInPlace({
         callback: function(unused, enteredText) { return enteredText; },
         show_buttons: false
    }); // --<
});
```

Comment: if using a more advanced jQuery 1.7+ version it is suggested to use .on() function.
See [here](http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/on-vs-live-review/) why.

Comment: This solution requires two clicks on the editable element to edit it.
Alternately, you can call the `live` function on the parent element of your editable content, with the `mouseenter` event instead of `click`, and change `this` to your editable field.